# (MYSQL) select 1 row on the first table, all rows in the second table, 1 row in the last table

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, select, multiple-tables

First post here. I decided to sign up because after having spent hours searching for an answers without success.

I am dealing with a problem, and my knowledges are just not good enough so far.

**Let's say I have 3 tables:**

*Items(item_id,title,group_id)

Item_options(option_id,item_id,option_title)

Item_group(group_id,group_title)*

I want to retrieve data using the variable $item_id in one single mysql query, but:

**1/**I want to return **only 1 row from "Items"**

**2/ All rows** from **"Item_options"** that are **linked to "item_id" from Items**

**3/** **1 row from Item_group** that is **linked to group_id in the table "Items"**.

**Here's my query so far:**

```
"SELECT * FROM Items as A LEFT JOIN Items_options AS B ON A.item_id=B.item_id LEFT JOIN Item_group AS C ON A.group_id=C.group_id WHERE A.item_id = '$item_id'"
```

It returns this (**an array that contains 4 arrays**, because there are 4 related rows in item_options):

```
Array(

Array 0:

A.item_id (1), A.item_title (mybox), **B.option_id (1), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto1)**, C.group_id (1), C.group_title (myvacation)

Array 1:

A.item_id (1), A.item_title (mybox), **B.option_id (2), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto2)**, C.group_id (1), C.group_title (myvacation)

Array 2:

A.item_id (1), A.item_title (mybox), **B.option_id (3), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto3)**, C.group_id (1), C.group_title (myvacation)

Array 4:

A.item_id (1), A.item_title (mybox), **B.option_id (4), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto4)**, C.group_id (1), C.group_title (myvacation)

)
```

But I don't want this! I want:

```
Array(

Array 0:

A.item_id (1), A.item_title (mybox), **B.option_id (1), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto1)**, C.group_id (1), C.group_title (myvacation)

Array 1:

NULL, NULL, **B.option_id (2),** **B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto2)**, NULL, NULL

Array 2:

NULL, NULL, **B.option_id (3),** **B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto3)**, NULL, NULL

Array 3:

NULL, NULL, **B.option_id (4), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto4)**, NULL, NULL

)
```

or even this would do:

```
Array(

Array 0:

A.item_id (1), A.item_title (mybox), **B.option_id (1), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto1)**, C.group_id (1), C.group_title (myvacation)

Array 1:

A.item_id (NULL), A.item_title (NULL), **B.option_id (2), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto2)**, C.group_id (NULL), C.group_title (NULL)

Array 2:

A.item_id (NULL), A.item_title (NULL), **B.option_id (3), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto3)**, C.group_id (NULL), C.group_title (NULL)

Array 3:

A.item_id (NULL), A.item_title (NULL), **B.option_id (4), B.item_id (1), B.option_title (myphoto4)**, C.group_id (NULL), C.group_title (NULL)

)
```

(The fields that I marked as **NULL could also be EMPTY**, it would do the job for what I want)

I'm desperate and I feel so dumb :(

Thanks in advance if anyone smart enough can help poor me.

Comment: Relational databases don't operate in terms of "first row from here, all from there and 1 from there", they operate by relations. Now what does this mean - in simple terms - it's much better that you issue 3 queries since your requirement goes out of scope of relations. Sometimes silly and plain solutions are the best ones - your requirement is simple in terms of human understanding but quite difficult to explain via SQL (although possible, I will skip doing it). My advice - 3 queries. Technically you wont lose on performance to a point where you'll feel it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Well, I think I can reduce it to 2. the Group table linked to item table, then loading the item option"s" since there are more than 1 row. For what it worths, I would still want to know if what I asked is possible, because I want to learn, even if it is not something to use here.